# Snapping gpx to Lines

Tags: qgis, snapping, gpx

I have made a map based on OSM vector data. I'd like to implement a lot of gpx files there, but the tracks of those do not really fit on the streets/paths of the osm data. is there a clever way to snap those gpx routes to the underlaying OSM data?[image: screenshot]

The dashed lines represent the OSM tracks and the full red line a gpx route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Menu `Processing > Toolbox > Snap Geometries to Layer`. Set your GPS track as `Input Layer` and use the OSM streets as `Reference layer`. Set a tolerance value and for `Behavior`, choose `Prefer closest point, insert extra vertices where required`. Change these values if the result is not optimal.

*Black: OSM tracks; red: gps track; blue: gps track snapped to OSM layer:*
[image]

Comment: This is really a good way and works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

A manual solution would involce snapping the vertices of the gps track to the closest point of the OSM paths. If there is a considerable disntance between vertices, consider first densifying the gps track (`Menu Processing > Toolbox > Densify by interval`).

Then use this expression with either Geometry generator (for visualisation only) or Geometry by expression (to generate actual geometries) - see here for [details about both options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814):

```
make_line (
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (1,  num_points( $geometry)),
        closest_point (
            aggregate ('OSM', 'collect', $geometry),  -- replace OSM with the name of your layer containing the OSM paths
            point_n( $geometry, @element)
        )
    )
)
```

Both solutions might run into problems where two OSM paths are very near and where the gps track crosses both. In such cases, you should repair manually or use [QGIS network tools](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html) to test if the resulting path can be followed inside the network of the OSM paths.

*The solution using Geomtry generator: blue line is the version of the red line snapped to the black paths. Be aware of one of the problematic spots (red dot):*

[image]

*Zoomed in to the problematic spot. This is difficult to avoid an should be checked using network tools.*
[image]